# Spring Boot property resolution fails tests at build time when adding a profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-test, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Boot **2.7.14** application packaged as follows:

`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.acquire`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.acquire.random`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.distribute`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.domain`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.generate`
`com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.process`

The root `*.dailycashreport` package contains the entry point:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:feeds-config.yml", factory = com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class DcrDataFactoryApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    

    
    @Autowired
    private SyntheticRunner runner; data sources

    public static void main(String[] args) {//}
```

**YamlPropertySourceFactory** seen above is as follows:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

There are the following 3 resources under `src/main/resources`:

**application.yml:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application

sftp:
  host: dev
  port: 22
  user: dev
  stagingDir: /opt/ccc/Data/Stage
  tmpDir: /opt/ccc/abcd/tmp
  #privateKey: 
  privateKey: file:///C:/Users/12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
  chmod: 664 
  
file:    
  stagingDir: /opt/ccc/Data/Stage
  tmpDir: C:\tmp
```

**feeds-config.yml**

```
feeds:
  downstream:
    another-system:
      output-file-name: other.txt
    daily-cash-report:
      output-file-name: dcr.txt
      test:
        records-to-generate:
          pc: 10
          dp: 5
          z: 1
```

and **logback.xml**

---

In tests, I'm using the following setup:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DataMarshallerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataMarshallerService cut;
    
    @Autowired
//
```

The above setup builds and works fine, however as soon as I'm trying to introduce a `dev` profile by renaming `application.yml` into `application-dev.yml`, I start encountering the following exception as part of the build **in tests execution**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'sftp.host' in value "${sftp.host}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
```

Here's the launch profile in my STS IDE:

[image]

However, the error manifests during the build time, when executing

```
mvn clear package -P dcr
```

which is equivalent to the following STS Maven config also present in STS:

[image]

What is it I'm missing so that Spring profiles start functioning properly?

Could it be that since the `*App` has `YamlPropertySourceFactory` configured, the rest of the properties need to be specified explicitly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set -Dspring.profiles.active=dev on your launch config ?

Comment: My launch config is configured with the `dev` profile (see picture above) but the error manifests during the **build** time, I'm able to just run it within IDE for a while before realizing its presence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made the following assumption and an attempt to validate it, it seems to work, so I'll leave it here as a potential answer to be, potentially, challenged.

**Apparently tests need to be pointed at the proper profile which is not part of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation itself.**

Either one of the following 3 configurations seem to make the build work:

**Option 1:**

I've updated all the failing test cases with the following annotation after the `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")
```

while adding the following stanza inside the `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application
  profiles: dev
```

It also works without the above stanza if I rename `application.yml` into `application-dev.yml`.

**Option 2:**

Another, even simpler approach is as follows:

1. no need to annotate all tests with additional `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")` as above while
2. running the build with the following Maven command instead:

```
mvn clean package -P dcr -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

and

3. consuming the `application-dev.yml` out of *src/main/resources/*

**Option 3**

No need to either:

- adding an `application-dev.yml` file
- or specifying an additional `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "dev")` annotation
- or needing to point to a specific profile as part of invocation of the build with `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`,
- or specifying `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` as a parameter to Maven

Simply:

Drop a copy of `application.yml` into *src/test/resources/* folder so as to be picked up and used for tests execution via  `mvn clean package -P dcr`

I'll let someone more authoritative to confirm that these are the right approaches and to validate that this test behavior in Spring is by design.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the standard properties file but only the dev one. Keep the `application.yml` and add a `application-dev.yml` in addition. In the standard one you add the following property:

```yaml
spring.profiles.active:
  - dev
  - another_profile
  - and_one_more_profile
```

Spring will now search for `application-dev.yml` in addition to the `application.yaml`. This way you can override the standards with properties from the -dev profile.

Or, as Gweltaz Niquel pointed out in his comment, you can also set profiles via system parameter.

Comment: Is this conjecture based on any official documentation?  I tried the above approach: introducing both `application.yml` with the following ```spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application
  profiles:
    active:
      -dev``` and an associated `application-dev.xml` as before, and it fails with the same error.  Why would one necessarily need to have what you call a `standard` yml, can't there be just the *dev*?

Comment: Spring only looks for `application.properties` or `application.yml` automatically if no other information is provided. It then reads this standard properties file and if inside here other propertiies files are specified these will also be read. Or, as Gweltaz said, you can tell Spring with system parameters which profiles to load, eg `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles