# Difference when executing tests via @SpringJUnitConfig vs @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, testing, dependency-injection, spring-test

In our test codebase, we are trying to minimize the usage of `@SpringBootTest` annotations in favor of more targeted `@SpringJUnitConfig`.

Replacing it in the first of the working tests:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
//@SpringBootTest
class DataMarshallerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataMarshallerService cut;
```

we start seeing the following stack:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.generate.DataMarshallerService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Similarly, during the build:

```
mvn clean package -P mvnProfile

[ERROR] Errors:                                                                                                                                                        
[ERROR]   DataMarshallerServiceTest.testSuccessfulFileGenerationViaBatches � UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstre
am.dailycashreport.generate.DataMarshallerServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoS
uchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.generate.DataMarshallerService' available: expected at 
least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                   
[ERROR]   DataMarshallerServiceTest.testTrailerAggregationsProduction � UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.da
ilycashreport.generate.DataMarshallerServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBe
anDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.generate.DataMarshallerService' available: expected at least
 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}                        
[INFO]
```

Participating in these tests, there are `@Bean`s created as part of `@Configuration` classes as well as the ones adorned with `@Component` and `@Service` to be resolved via classpath scanning.

For example, the above class under test:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DataMarshallerService {//}
```

The `src/main/resources` contains `application-dev.yml` properties file while there's a corresponding `application.yml` in `src/test/resources`.

**application.yml** (used in tests):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application
  #profiles: dev

sftp:
  in:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    landingDir: C:\ABC #/opt/EAF/Data/Stage
    tmpDir: /opt/EAF/ephub/tmp
    localDir: /opt/EAF/ephub/tmp
    fetchSize: 1
    privateKey: 
    #privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x123345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 
    poller:
      fixedDelay: 10000
  out:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    stagingDir: C:\ABC #/opt/EAF/Data/Stage
    tmpDir: /opt/EAF/ephub/tmp
    privateKey: 
    #privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 
  
file:
  out:
    stagingDir: C:\ABC #/opt/EAF/Data/Stage
    tmpDir: C:\ABC
```

Doesn't `@SpringJUnitConfig` do the normal classpath scanning? What could be missing or misconfigured in this setup?

Thank you in advance.

---

Supplying the 2 `@Configuration` classes to the new annotation (while leaving the ones with `@Service`, `@Component`, etc. as is:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes= {FileAcquisitionConfig.class, FileDistributionConfig.class})
class DataMarshallerServiceTest {//}
```

results in another error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${sftp.in.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

whereas same properties resolve fine under `@SpringBootTest`.

Here's an excerpt from one of the configuration files above, containing the culprit `${sftp.in.host}`, for reference:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class FileAcquisitionConfig {

    public final static String RECEIVER_CHANNEL = "fromSftpChannel";
    
    
    //sftp
    
    @Value("${sftp.in.host}") @Getter
    private String host;

    @Value("${sftp.in.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${sftp.in.user}")
    private String user;

//. . .
```

---

Another experiment per suggestion:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes= {DcrDataFactoryApplication.class, FileAcquisitionConfig.class, FileDistributionConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yml" })
//@SpringBootTest
class DataMarshallerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataMarshallerService cut;
```

results in the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'sftp.out.host' in value "${sftp.out.host}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of experimentation, I've come up with the setup that seems to work.  The assumptions which I was making to come up with the setup and to base my thought process on are described below.

Given there are many pieces to the setup and the fact that **Spring Boot documentation** never completely **explains the rationale** for having (or not having) certain attributes on certain annotations, but not on the others, as well as the inter-relationships and **potential use cases for various possible combinations and permutations** of different annotations' variants, this answer represents only what has worked for me at this point - feel free to contradict and challenge it, a clearer explanation will certainly benefit the community and is most welcome.

As described in the initial question, there seems to be an **asymmetry** between how `@SpringBootTest` and  `@SpringJUnitConfig` with its various associated annotations handle reading of properties, in yaml format or otherwise, resolving dependencies (designated with `@Config` or other `@Bean`/`@Service`/`@Component`, etc. stereotypes), etc.

That's why, among other items of the `classes` attribute of the `@SpringJUnitConfig` I've added the `DcrDataFactoryApplication.class` to attempt to pull every scannable component on the classpath as the next two members there `FileAcquisitionConfig.class` and `FileDistributionConfig.class`, being `@Configuration`'s themselves only contained the `@Bean` designanted types and clearly didn't make much of a difference:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes= {DcrDataFactoryApplication.class, FileAcquisitionConfig.class, FileDistributionConfig.class})
```

That still didn't work, as described in the updates to the original question, so I started playing with the `@TestPropertySource`'s members - having added just `locations = { "classpath:application.yml" }` didn't cut it, so I then noticed it allows for another attribute, `properties`, so I started to add different properties from the `application.yml` to it incrementally:

```
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = { "classpath:application.yml" }, 
        properties={"sftp.out.host=eafdev", "sftp.out.port=22"})
```

and that's when I started seeing a difference - whatever is added via `properties` gets resolved and overrides the same properties inside of `application.yml` + eliminating the Spring's **irrelevant** String to int coercion error message.

That seemed to indicate that, opposite to `@SpringBootTest`, the `@TestPropertySource` doesn't have the ability to process YAML files out of the box which prompted me to look in that direction.

[Some blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource) indicated that, indeed, Spring Boot by default doesn't load YAML which is when I recalled that aside from `@SpringBootApplication` I earlier attached the following to my `DcrDataFactoryApplication.class`:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:feeds-config.yml", factory = com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class DcrDataFactoryApplication  implements CommandLineRunner  {//}
```

where `YamlPropertySourceFactory.class` is as follows, per above mentioned blog:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

With that discovery, I started looking at ways I can enable the testing infrastructure with that Yaml resolver, given that `@TestPropertySource` doesn't have a comparable `factory` attribute to pass that resolver in, as shown above, nor does the **presence** of `DcrDataFactoryApplication` on the `@SpringJUnitConfig(classes=` array, **with its knowledge of how to resolve Yaml-formatted property** files make any difference either.

That led me to downgrading the setup to using a`@PropertySource` instead of `@TestPropertySource` as the former does have an attribute to activate that linking to a factory:

```
@PropertySource(value = "application.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

That approach seems to be seconded by the discussions I found in another blog, or rather a [thread on the Spring projects Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10772).

Plus it highlighted the need for yet another participant in this testing orgy, namely `@EnableConfigurationProperties`.

So, cutting the long story short, here's the final overall test setup that I've come up with:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes= {DcrDataFactoryApplication.class, FileAcquisitionConfig.class, FileDistributionConfig.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "application.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

That allows me to completely remove `@SpringBootTest` dependency and replace it with more verbose, cryptic, but hopefully (per Spring documents) more targeted approach in our tests.

This approach has been tested on a couple of test classes and seems to hold the water so far.

Feel free to point out any shortcomings or if I'm inadvertently misinterpreting any of the initial Spring Boot's vision for such test setup.

I highlighted a couple of things in Spring Boot, that could potentially be either more documented / explained or improved.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I was looking for the same, trying to move away from SpringBoot, your solution worked like a charm :).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you need to indicate the configuration to use.  You can either use a Config.class or a spring configuration file.

Example Config class:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(TestConfig.class)
```

Example configuration file:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(locations = "/test-config.xml")
```

The subsequent problem you encountered regarding injection of value properties should be resolved by including the following class level annotation on your test class:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yaml" })
```

This annotation should load the properties from your `application.yaml` file in the `src/test/resources` directory.

Comment: Thank you, I did try providing configs as you are suggesting, but that results in different set of errors, please see my updates

Comment: In order inject the properties in the test context add the following class level annotation @TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.yaml" }) .  This should load the properties from your application.yaml file in the src/test/resources directory.

Comment: Same error as before, please see the update.

Comment: Ok then also add the contextInitializer to help with the @Value injection.  @SpringJUnitConfig(classes= {DcrDataFactoryApplication.class, FileAcquisitionConfig.class, FileDistributionConfig.class},initializers={ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class})

Comment: Given it's an internal Spring's class, how does adding it to the mix help?

Comment: According to this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer is an ApplicationContextInitializer that you can apply to your tests to load Spring Boot application.properties files.